# Display the total number of each catagory in each column seperately -- SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, summary

Where is a database like

| gender | ssc_b |
| --- | --- |
| F | Central |
| F | Central |
| F | Other |
| M | Central |
| M | Other |

I used the count and group by command but it shows:

| gender | num_gender | ssc_b | num_ssc_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | 2 | Central | 2 |
| F | 1 | Other | 1 |
| M | 1 | Central | 1 |
| M | 1 | Other | 1 |

I want the display the total number of each catagory in each column seperately, like

| gender | num_gender | ssc_b | num_ssc_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | 3 | Central | 3 |
| M | 2 | Other | 2 |

Comment: Where did the 'F','Other' go (in your results)? or 'M','Central'?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: There's no apparent logical reason in your output, could you explain in detail where the values of the counts come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT gender as key, count(*) as value
FROM <table>
GROUP BY gender
UNION ALL
SELECT ssc_b as key, count(*) as value
FROM <table>
GROUP BY ssc_b
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for what you asked, the answer is

```
select a.gender, a.s, b.gender, b.s from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num_row, gender, sum(num_gender) s from t group by gender) a 
outer join 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num_row, ssc_b, sum(num_ssc_b) s from t group by ssc_b) b 
on a.num_row=b.num_row
```

But maybe more logical would be to have the inner queries above as two separate queries.